# Is there a way through VBA to emulate a button click, when the button is a DIV with event handling disabled?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I have been a fan of you guys for years I am hoping that someone can assist. I have been working on and off on this problem to no avail for almost a year now hopefully someone out there might be able to help!

In short I have a series of fields on a website accompanied by what appear to be buttons.

Like so:

```html
<div tabindex="9" class="gwt-PushButton gwt-PushButton-up" role="button" id="ClientSearchView.clientIdSubmitBtn" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 100px;"><input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
  <div class="html-face">Submit</div>
</div>
```

And also:

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="gwt-PushButton gwt-PushButton-up" role="button" aria-pressed="false" id="BackDateSystemDatePopup.useSysDateBtn" style="width: 190px;"><input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
  <div class="html-face">Use Current System Date</div>
</div>
```

I have tried all iterations of using the fire event methods and went through each one there are no errors merely nothing happens.

I have tried just object.click as well to no avail. It seems the site uses an aria state for validation to disable event listening, if any one has any assistance or insight I would be deeply indebted.

Comment: Try these `IE.document.getElementById("ClientSearchView.clientIdSubmitBtn").click()
IE.document.getElementById("ClientSearchView.clientIdSubmitBtn").FireEvent("onclick")
IE.document.querySelector("#ClientSearchView.clientIdSubmitBtn").Click()`

Comment: What changes to those elements do you observe when manually clicking? 1) Are they clickable? 2) Do any of the attribute values changes e.g. does  aria-pressed change from False to True ? 3) Do you have an example webpage which replicates this problem?

Comment: @Santosh thank you for your help I have tried all of those to no avail same result. However when I try queryselector it errors out. I'm thinking I might have the syntax wrong.

Comment: @QHarr Ok so a few things 1) Yes always clickable (for instance if I actually click the button 2) So there are two changes I noticed for class it goes from class="gwt-PushButton gwt-PushButton-up", Then I place the mouse over and it goes to class="gwt-PushButton gwt-PushButton-up-hovering", And when I press the button it changes to class="gwt-PushButton gwt-PushButton-down-hovering"  and then aria-pressed changes to true. If that helps. 3) Unfortunately its a proprietary site for work I don't have a public example. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Can you attempt to set these attribute values?

Comment: for your queryselector try ie.document.querySelector("[id='ClientSearchView.clientIdSubmitBtn']").Click instead.

Comment: @TimVanderzeil don't have much choice in the matter. I appreciate your advice and while I might be able to utilize it elsewhere it is unfortunately inappropriate for my needs.

Comment: @QHarr I cannot set them. For example all I get after trying to execute this is an error saying Expecting = ie.document.getElementbyID("BackDateSystemDatePopup.useSysDateBtn").SetAttribute("aria-pressed", "true")

Comment: @QHarr whenever I attempt to use querySelector I am told the object doesn't support the property or method.

Comment: Are you using IE8 or if you look in dev tools at the emulation is it set to less than IE9 for document mode?

Comment: @RY M, I suggest you to post your VBA code that you had tried on your side may help us to understand the issue in better way. also try to make a test with any other machine to check whether you are able to run your code that or not.

Comment: @QHarr I do not know how to add a screen shot to a comment, but Document Mode is: "11 (Default)" Browser Profile: "Desktop", User Agent String "Internet Explorer 11 (Default)" under emulation rather

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thank you as well as QHarr for your assistance, I apologize. This time of the month (the 2nd week of the new month) is my busiest. I will endeavor to provide you both as soon as possible and thank you once again for your assistance .